# How to refresh app when opened from deeplink?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am struggling with a react native app. I would implement react native firebase dynamic link, but now I am a little lost. I use this method on HomeScreen which working perfectly every times when somebody opens the app.

```
async componentWillMount() {
    try {
      let url = await firebase.links().getInitialLink();
      if(url) {
        let api = "example.com/user/123456";
        try {
          this.setState({ data: "John Doe" });
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Preview', {user: this.state.data })
        }
        catch {
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
    }
  }
```

But when the app is already opened this method doesn't work properly. Is there a way where I can trigger a function every time when somebody comes back to the opened app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a tip, you should place your code in `componentDidMount` so that you do not block the initial (first) render.

You could use [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) to listen out for changes to apps being put in the background/foreground.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.showPreview();
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange);
}

const onAppStateChange = appState => {
  // You can check if appState is active/background/foreground
  this.showPreview();
}

const showPreview = async (appState) => {
    // You can check if appState is active/inactive/background
    try {
      let url = await firebase.links().getInitialLink();
      if(url) {
        let api = "example.com/user/123456";
        try {
          this.setState({ data: "John Doe" });
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Preview', {user: this.state.data })
        }
        catch {
        }
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
```